# Rules for Factorisation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wondered if someone could explain the steps in the example below? In particular, how to arrive at (1+R)P.

The example is given:

V = RP+P = (1+R)P

Would be appreciated.

Best,

Andrew

Comment: Notice that $V = RP + P = P + RP$.  Now apply the distributive law $ac + bc = (a + b)c$.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful!

Comment: It helps if you express $P$ as $1 \cdot P$.